# Analyse and compare non-stationary time-dependent signals

Tags: time-series, correlation, stationarity

I need a sanity check. I am working with a data set of force-time, displacement-time, and velocity-time signals. All of my signals are non-stationary, and they contain trends (low frequency variations) and periodicity (high-frequency variations). I am interested in analysing the frequency content of different signals and in comparing different signals with each other. I have been reading a lot into different techniques that could be applicable to my problem, and at this point I feel like I am reading conflicting information. This is what I have been doing so far:

1. Calculate the Power/Amplitude density spectrum of the entire spectrum and of selected events to study the frequency content
2. Plot the cumulative power spectral density to see how the frequency content changes between different signals
3. Wavelet plots to study how the frequency content changes over time
4. Plot the autocorrelation function to find the fundamental frequency of each signal
5. Plot the autocorrelation function of the filtered signal to focus on higher frequency content
6. (To be done) plot correlation functions between different signals to compare them or to compare part of a signal to the entire signal (event detection)
7. Calculate the Pearson Correlation Coefficient for different signals to get an overall idea of similarity

Does it make sense to use these techniques event when my signal is not stationary? Do I necessarily need to make my signals stationary using differencing? I have no interest in forecasting or modelling, I really just want to analyze my signals qualitatively. Also, is there any other technique that I could be looking into?

Thank you already!